# Stored procedure for Searching in a text using multiple likes (NO Full-Text Search)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Imagine I have a comma separated string list like `@DSC='Watch,Water Proof,LED Screen'` and I'd like to select those records in where description contains items in `@DSC` variable. Here's a simple query for that:

```
SELECT * FROM GoodInfo
WHERE Description LIKE '%Watch%'
AND Description LIKE '%Water Proof%'
AND Description LIKE '%LED Screen%'
```

And here's the table's columns:

```
Id | Name | CategoryId | Description | Price
```

A sample Description field for one of those goods goes like this:

`Men's Digital Sports Watch LED Screen Large Face Military Watches and Waterproof Casual Luminous Stopwatch Alarm Simple Army`

Extend this example where you want to search for a good with a comma separated string list with less or more properties.

What I'm looking for is a stored procedure that gives a comma separated string list as a parameter then split it and depend on the count of gained items create the select query, so I would just execute something like following command:

```
EXEC SearchFor 'Watch,Water Proof,LED Screen,Digital'
```

Comment: Consider normalizing your schema replacing the strings with table rows instead of working around that bad design.

Comment: To add on to what @stickybit is saying, it might be worth making a table of "tags", which is just an ID and a word, like `1  |   water proof, 2  |  digital`. Then another table linking items to their tags, like `ItemID   |   TagId`.  If a watch had 5 tags, it would have 5 records in the link table.

Comment: I know what you mean, **it's just an example** to demonstrate my intention and to know how I should search on text without using Full-Text search technology in SQL server.

Comment: I would parse the CSV by comma, write all the values to a table, then loop through each value and pull your data vua dynamic sql inside your proc

Comment: In any case, you should really provide your own attempt, rather than asking someone to write the query for you.

Comment: Also worth noting that this is going to be a horribly slow query if the size of the table gets to any size.

Answer (score 1):

Search for a `split()` function . . . one is available since SQL Server 2016.

Then you can just do:

```
SELECT *
FROM GoodInfo gi CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_vals,
             SUM(CASE WHEN description LIKE '%' + val + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_matches
      FROM (split_string(@DSC, ',')) ss(val)
     ) v
WHERE v.num_vals = n.num_matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with this database design, I suggest manipulating your comma-separated string to create a query string, and passing that through sp_executesql.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchFor   
    @input nvarchar(max)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @input = REPLACE(@input, ',', ' AND Description LIKE ''%');
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
    SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM GoodInfo WHERE Description LIKE ''%' + @input + '%''';
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query;
GO
```

But ultimately, these values should probably be in their own column and not just dumped into `Comments` where things tend to get lost and querying gets tedious. And as pointed out in the comments, this example is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Edit: I learned something new! If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, you can use the [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) predicate, and use 'AND' instead of commas to separate your list:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchFor   
    @input nvarchar(max)
AS
    SELECT * FROM GoodInfo WHERE CONTAINS(Description, @input)
GO
```

Comment: And if the string contains apostrophes? You've also just opened up a massive security hole (i.e. SQL injection, very naughty)

Comment: Worth noting the enormous injection potential if this were to fall into malicious hands. **EDIT:** The answer isn't *wrong*, so I don't agree with the downvotes. If he is the only one running this stored proc and is just doing it to save himself some time, the injection point might be moot.

Comment: you used sp_executesql, why not use the parameters to avoid the injection instead of concatenating it into the string?

Comment: OP wanted to split a single parameter into multiple parameters... It's the only way I could think to handle his/her requirements.

Comment: you could use `set quoted_identifier off` to get around the apostrophe issue, but the injection issue is legit

Comment: Error message: `Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'GoodInfo' because it is not full-text indexed`. meaning I  have to add fulltext index on specific fields I want to search which is what I didn't tend in the first palce.